# Renewing a conditional green card

Tags: usa, greencard

I received my Green Card on `07/25/2016` as a result of my wife's sponsorship. In my card, I see that the expiration date is set to `07/25/2018` since I have a conditional permanent status of 2 years.

I am planning to take a vacation outside of the US between May 2018 and the end of June 2018. That way I would still have 25 days before my card expires.

My questions is, will there be any issues for me to get back into the US if I return by the end of June? I am planning to apply for a renewal before I leave the country and will that void the existing green card I have? Can I travel with a 2 year green card while I have already applied for the renewal and is in process?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with you re-entering with the old green card before it expires (that's what the expiration date means -- you can use it up to and including that date).

If you will have received your I-751 receipt (which serves as a one-year extension letter) already, you can even return *after* 7/25/2018 with the expired card and extension letter with no problems.

Comment: What happens if I get a `biometrics` appearance date while I am out of the country?

Comment: You just call them and reschedule. Might cost you several months, though.